# Branch that includes non consecutive revisions

Tags: mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

Suppose I have a revision history with no branching like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now I want to create a new branch in my repository with revision `1` and `3`, but not revision `2` or `4`.  There are no conflicting updates in revisions `2`/`3`.  Is there a way to do this.  My final repository should have two branches like this:

```
4
3
2  3
| /
|/
1
```

Comment: @Lazy Badger, why did you remove revision 3 from the main branch?  I want to have it there if possible.

Comment: If my impression was wrong - I'll fix it. Mainline will be 1-2-3-4 and only 3 **copied** to new parent, yes?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry if that was not clear originally.

Comment: in **this** case term "branch" mostly haven't sense, because you want to copy one changeset into some new location. And answer will be one command rebase `hg rebase --keep -s 2 -d 0`

Comment: Reverted the question to show what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already published this repo to a public location (or any developer has cloned your repo), you can do this with a combination of `graft` and `backout`.

The `graft` command will copy a commit from one branch to another.  The `backout` command will reverse the changes made by an earlier commit.

The following example should replicate your situation:

```
hg init test
echo test>>test\test.txt && hg -R test ci -Am "baseline"
echo test>>test\test.txt && hg -R test ci -Am "changeset 1"
echo test>>test\test.txt && hg -R test ci -Am "changeset 2"
echo new>>test\new.txt   && hg -R test ci -Am "changeset 3"
echo test>>test\test.txt && hg -R test ci -Am "changeset 4"
hg -R test backout -r 3
hg -R test ci -m "backed out changeset 3"
hg -R test update -r 1
hg -R test graft -r 3
hg -R test glog --template "{desc}\n"
```

This creates a new anonymous branch with the changes you wanted and also removes the changes in rev 3 from the original branch without modifying the history of your repository.

This results in the following log:

```
@  changeset 3
|
| o  backed out changeset 3
| |
| o  changeset 4
| |
| o  changeset 3
| |
| o  changeset 2
|/
o  changeset 1
|
o  baseline
```

Comment: @LazyBadger: I've updated my answer...can you explain your objection in more detail?  I don't understand what you mean by "backout is just from another story".

Comment: I can't show `glog` in comment, but I tested - you'll got another tree, than rewritten by OP request: backout create additional commit

Comment: While it is true that backout creates an additional commit, it does not create another tree.  It simply creates a new commit that reverses the changes.  The result is the same.  Also, this is the only method that works without rewriting repo history (important for shared projects).

Comment: Not backout, but **your sequence of commands**. Do you want to see full output of your commands-set?

Comment: I'll save you the effort.  A test script and output are now included in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Because you said nothing about named branch, we work with anonymous branching

Before:

```
>hg glog --template "{rev}:{desc}\n"
@  3:Added d.txt
|
o  2:Added c.txt
|
o  1:Added b.txt
|
o  0:Initial commit

>hg rebase -s 2 -d 0

>hg glog --template "{rev}:{desc}\n"

@  3:Added d.txt
|
o  2:Added c.txt
|
| o  1:Added b.txt
|/
o  0:Initial commit

>hg rebase -s 3 -d 1

>hg glog --template "{rev}:{desc}\n"
@  3:Added c.txt
|
| o  2:Added d.txt
| |
o |  1:Added b.txt
|/
o  0:Initial commit
```

In case of named branch you have to `hg branch BRANCHNAME` and `hg ci -m "Creating branch"` before first rebase, use -d 4 in rebase instead of 0

Comment: Definitely worth throwing in the warning that if you've already pushed this repo somewhere then it's too late to rebase.

Comment: @Ry4an: Phases obsoleted such warning

Comment: Most people still aren't running builds with phases.  I'll leave the warning.

Comment: It's not that simple! You don't show the descendants of rev 3, but they will move along with it when you rebase. So you also have to rebase rev 4 back onto rev 2. And if the surrounding history is non-linear, you have to tread really carefully.

Comment: @alexis - I **have not** descendants of rev 3, totally. I copy-paste full output of real repo, without editiing. In case of more long history - yes, it will be more long dances and more chances for MQ

Comment: I see that you don't, but the OP wanted to cherry-pick 3 and leave 2 and 4 behind. So the fate of descendants is relevant, but missing from your nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like you're trying to accomplish what's called "cherrypicking": Selectively **copy** some changesets to another branch, without treating them as a merge. If that's correct, you can do it by first creating an ordinary branch off revision one, then grafting onto it the changesets you want to copy. The command **[hg graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft)** is designed for this purpose.

Here's how it would work with a named branch, `selective`. If you want unnamed branches, just omit the branch creation.

```
hg update -r 1
hg branch selective
hg graft -r 3
```

The result will look like this (which, I hope, is what you wanted):

```
4
|
3
|  5 = 3
2 /
|/
1
|
0
```

By default, graft will copy user, date, and description from the source changeset(s). The new revision will have identical effects to revision 3, but will have a new numeric and hash id. Mercurial will not be aware of the relationship between revisions 3 and 5.

There's no way to selectively import some changesets and treat the operation as a merge: Merging always unifies the complete (linear) history up to the point being merged.